# Python MySQL connecting to database error

Tags: python, mysql, database

I'm trying to create a small app with Python and MySQL.
I managed to connect Python and MySQL using the MySQL connection. But now when I try to run this script to actually connect to the database:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    passwd="12345", 
    db="DB", 
    host="hostname", 
    user="root"
    )
print(mydb)
```

I get a lot of errors like:

```
 File "C:\Users\Krystian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 485, in open_connection
socket.SOL_TCP)

File "C:\Users\Krystian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
File "c:/Users/Krystian/Desktop/DB/db.py", line 7, in <module>
    user="root"

  File "C:\Users\Krystian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Krystian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Krystian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 722, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Krystian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 207, in _open_connection
    self._socket.open_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Krystian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 501, in open_connection
    errno=2003, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'hostname:3306' (11001 getaddrinfo failed)
```

I tried other ways of conecting to Database but they didn't work and I'm not really sure what to do now.

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT1

As *Juergen* mentioned, after fixing the hostname most of the errors above are gone, but new ones showed up:

```
File "C:\Users\Krystian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Krystian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 722, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Krystian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 211, in _open_connection
    self._ssl)
  File "C:\Users\Krystian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 141, in _do_auth
    auth_plugin=self._auth_plugin)
  File "C:\Users\Krystian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\protocol.py", line 102, in make_auth
    auth_data, ssl_enabled)
  File "C:\Users\Krystian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\protocol.py", line 58, in _auth_response
    auth = get_auth_plugin(auth_plugin)(
  File "C:\Users\Krystian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\authentication.py", line 191, in get_auth_plugin
    "Authentication plugin '{0}' is not supported".format(plugin_name))
mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supporte
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess, your computer (where the database runs) is not named "hostname":

```
    host="hostname",
```

If it is the local machine, try `localhost`. "hostname" is just a placeholder inside example coding. You always have to replace such.

About your edit:

Looks as your db server is misconfigured. Maybe you need that plugin that is named in the error message.

Comment: Just fixed that, old errors disappeared but new errors appeared

Comment: Ok, changing the security back to legacy removed the error about the plugin. Rest of the errors still there

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="user_name",
        passwd="db_password",
        database="db_name")
```

Comment: No luck with this